# Azure DevOps agent ignores demand if it set with "equals"

Tags: azure-devops

I noticed that is's impossible to use azure pipeline demand with "equals" way.
I mean, I have the docker azp-agent with this environment variable:
export FOO=BAR.

And if I use this structure in my pipeline, it works as expected:

```
demands:
  -FOO
```

But if I set the exact value, the pipeline won't run on this agent.

```
  demands:
    - FOO -equals BAR
```

did you guys notice this behavior? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. I added "pool:" twice. Once global with demands and the second time inside a job.